# Jenkins build number to be replaced with Tag or Commit ID

Tags: git, jenkins

Is there a plugin which replaces Jenkins build number with the Tag the commit points to or in the absence of a tag the commit ID. I know this can be scripted and then using Build Name Setter Plugin i can modify the name (it does not work if my build fails) but is there any other nice plugin to perform the above function?

Comment: Theoretically, you can build a single commit multiple times, so wouldn't this potentially lead to id collision?

Comment: Nope, I am not worried if multiple builds have same build name. I just want an easy way of looking at my build log at the end of the day. Build numbers force me to go into the log and search. My set up is such that I have a jobs per branch.

Comment: I am not sure if there are such plugins, maybe some scm plugins provide such feature. Otherwise if you use Jenkins Pipeline you can `currentBuild.name=your_tag here`.Or groovy postbuild plugin with something like `manager.build.description=your_tag_here`. In both cases you will need to run some code to prepare `your_tag` value. Most likely it will be shell + envinject pair of step.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend to change the build number with revision. Easiest way is to set a [description](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Description+Setter+Plugin).

Then it's a matter of:

1. Add build step in the build section of the job
2. Select "Add build description"
3. Add your Tag to the description
4. Description will be shown right next to the build number

Good luck!